# Lost sqlite3 module from python after OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, django, sqlite, osx-mavericks

After installing OS X Mavericks, I have been having issues running django's server:

```
(rango_tutorial)christohersmbp2:tango_with_django_project christopherspears$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): dlopen(/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

I think the issue is that the sqlite3 module has gone missing for some reason:

```
(rango_tutorial)christohersmbp2:tango_with_django_project christopherspears$ python 
Python 2.7.5 (default, Dec 31 2013, 11:46:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

I'm not sure what is causing this.  Isn't the sqlite3 module normally just part of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Updating OS X is notorious for messing up all sorts of Developer Tools.

What is your output when you type `which sqlite3`? How about other developer tools like `which gcc`? If they are missing you may need to reinstall Xcode. I know many users had to reinstall XCode after updating to Mavericks.

Here's the link for more information: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Got /usr/bin/sqlite3 and /usr/bin/gcc, so those are not missing.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling python with brew seemed to help with the earlier problem.  Of course now, python is broken in that virtual environment:

```
(rango_tutorial)christohersmbp2:tango_with_django_project christopherspears$ python manage.py runserver
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
(rango_tutorial)christohersmbp2:tango_with_django_project christopherspears$ python
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/christopherspears/.virtualenvs/rango_tutorial/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Okay...figured this out.  My python architecture has really changed.  This has the explanation: http://debugfix.com/2011/11/dyld-library-loaded-executable_path-python/